# RadScheduler - Timeline view resource title

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

I am using RadScheduler timeline view. 
Please find an attached telerik demo screenshot. Is it possible to show a resource title in timeline view?

[image] [image]

Thanks,
Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi some how I managed to get the wrong question: here is a full description and answer to my orignal problem:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/timeline-row-height-auto-height.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible. I tested it with the dropdown configurator here and it looks doable:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/resourcegrouping/defaultcs.aspx